Drop shadow applied depending on background
I am trying to understand why applying a drop shadow to a SwiftUI Text View is different when using a "clear" color versus a non-clear one like "blue".
#Preview {
    VStack {
        Text("Blue box")
            .background(.blue)
            // adds drop shadow to the bounding rectangle
            .clipped()
            .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)

        Text("Clear box")
            .background(.clear)
            // adds drop shadow to every letter
            .clipped()
            .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)

        Spacer()
    }
    .background(.yellow)
    .padding()
}

The code above produces this


The .clipped() modifier seems to be having the same effect as .compositingGroup() would have. If you comment it out then the letters have a shadow in the blue version too, as well as the background having a shadow:
Text("Blue box")
    .background(.blue)
    // .clipped()
    .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)


To confirm that composition is happening, try applying different levels of opacity to the background:
VStack(spacing: 20) {
    Text("Opacity 0.0")
        .background(.white.opacity(0.0))
        .clipped()
        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)
    Text("Opacity 0.1")
        .background(.white.opacity(0.1))
        .clipped()
        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)
    Text("Opacity 0.5")
        .background(.white.opacity(0.5))
        .clipped()
        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)
    Text("Opacity 1.0")
        .background(.white.opacity(1.0))
        .clipped()
        .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)
    Spacer()
}
.background(.yellow)
.padding()


You will notice that opacity 0.1 has some shadowing around the letters and a hint of a shadow behind the background. At 0.5 the shadow behind the (semi-transparent) background is beginning to dominate and the shadowing on the letters is no longer distinct. At 1.0, the background is opaque, so the shadowing happening behind it can only be seen at the edges.
As a general rule, if you only want the shadow to be around the background then it needs to be applied to the background itself:
Text("Blue box")
    .background {
        Color.blue
            .shadow(color: .black, radius: 2)
    }
    // .clipped()


